# How to set RBAC in this values.yaml?

Tags: kubernetes, rbac, open-policy-agent

Inside the file **values.yaml** of the [OPA](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/opa/values.yaml) chart I must activate RBAC using the following section :

```
# NOTE IF you use these, remember to update the RBAC rules below to allow
#      permissions to get, list, watch, patch and update configmaps
    enabled: false
    namespaces: [opa, kube-federation-scheduling-policy]
    requireLabel: true
  replicate:
# NOTE IF you use these, remember to update the RBAC rules below to allow
#      permissions to replicate these things
    cluster: []
#     - [group/]version/resource
    namespace: []
#     - [group/]version/resource
    path: kubernetes
```

As stated above I must add the verbs: **get, list, watch, patch and update** to the kind **configmap**.

*Unfortunatly I've got no idear how to make them fit the yaml...*

---

I don't understand the following syntaxe :

```
cluster: []
#     - [group/]version/resource
    namespace: []
#     - [group/]version/resource
    path: kubernetes
```

But I guess that the verbs fit in there somehow...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add following stanza in the **values.yaml** file

```
rbac:
  # If true, create & use RBAC resources
  #
  create: true
  rules:
    cluster:
     - apiGroups:
         - ""
       resources:
         - configmaps
       verbs:
         - get
         - list
         - watch
         - patch
         - update
```

Comment: When they wrote `RBAC rules below` they dit not mean the ones directly under. 40 lines down I found the rbac section that YOU found... I totaly had mist it ! Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

It's better to put all RBAC rules in a template and use a toggle to render that template, but it is also possible to put the rules in values.yaml and render it.

**Example:**

In **values.yaml**, provide a section like this:

```
rbac:
  enabled: true
  rules:
  - apiGroups: [""]
    resources: ["pods"]
    verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

In a template (e.g template/rbac.yaml), responsible for generating the rendered rbac manifest:

```
{{- if .Values.rbac.enabled -}}
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  name: pod-reader
rules:
{{ toYaml .Values.rbac.rules | indent 2 }}
---
....
{{- end -}}
```

Verify the output k8s manifests:

```
$ helm install -f values.yaml . --dry-run --debug
```